# Unable to render Canvas due to TypeError: Cannot read property 'getImageData' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get a react application to render the conways life method. I am still a bit new to React.js and was hoping someone could shed some light on why my code is broken and also how to fix it. And perhaps how to prevent it from happening in the future. Below is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Life from './life';
import './App.css';

/**
 * Life canvas
 */
class LifeCanvas extends Component {
  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.life = new Life(props.width, props.height);
    this.life.randomize();
  }

  /**
   * Component did mount
   */
  componentDidMount() {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this.animFrame();
    });
  }

  /**
   * Handle an animation frame
   */
  animFrame() {
    //
    // !!!! IMPLEMENT ME !!!!
    //
    let width = this.props.width;
    let height = this.props.height;

    // Request another animation frame
    // Update life and get cells
    let cells = this.life.getCells();

    // Get canvas framebuffer, a packed RGBA array
    let canvas = this.refs.canvas;
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2D');
    let imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);

    // Convert the cell values into white or black for the canvas
    for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        let index = (y * width + x) * 4;

        let lifeStatus = cells[y][x];
        let color = lifeStatus === 0 ? 0xff : 0x00;

        imageData.data[index + 0] = color; // R
        imageData.data[index + 1] = color; // G
        imageData.data[index + 1] = color; // B
        imageData.data[index + 1] = color; // A
      }
    }
    // Put the new image data back on the canvas
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

    // Next generation of life
    this.life.step();
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this.animFrame();
    });
  }

  /**
   * Render
   */
  render() {
    return (
      <canvas
        ref="canvas"
        width={this.props.width}
        height={this.props.height}
      />
    );
  }
}

/**
 * Life holder component
 */
class LifeApp extends Component {
  /**
   * Render
   */
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <LifeCanvas width={600} height={600} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

/**
 * Outer App component
 */
class App extends Component {
  /**
   * Render
   */
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <LifeApp />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When it renders the page the error in the subject line is produced in big red letters. I am not sure what it means. Please help.

Comment: It seems taht you are getting an undefined `canvas` variable...can you add a `console.dir` or a `console.log` in order to check the value at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is saying `ctx` is `null`. `getContext()` will return `null` when the passed context type is not valid. In your case you passed [`2D` the proper context type string is `2d`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext#Parameters)

```js
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2D');
console.log("ctx is: ",ctx);

ctx = c.getContext('2d');
console.log("ctx is now: ",ctx);
```

Comment: The line that it shows is wrong is the
`let imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);`

Comment: @JonathanReeves yes because ctx is null. Cannot read property getImageData of null is saying ctx is null therefore it cannot read the property named getImageData from it

Comment: I actually figured it out earlier. I appreciate the posts. Than y'all so much.